# USB TYPE-C ALT-MODE DisplayPort + USB 2.0, is it supported?

Tags: usb, displayport

DipslayPort 4 lanes are supported through usb type-c alternate mode. USB power delivery and usb 2.0 is always supported with the displayport alternate mode.

Powerdelivery is not crucial however usb is so critical for me. I need a passive type-c dp output with a usb 2.0. However I cannot find any low cost passive type c converter with these features.

According to this paper it should be possible:
https://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/USB-DevDays-DisplayPort-Alternate-Mode-2016-final4.pdf

Do I understand something wrong? Does anybody know any kind of schematic that I can make this at least by myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything to "covert from to". If you want DP over Type-C, you must have the raw DP output from your system, so there is nothing to convert. You might need however some CC controller that will advertise your port as ALT-MODE DP to an external DP device, which might happen over a subset of PD communication channel. You need to check with requirements on how to advertise the ALT-MODE DP. So having DP might be "critical".

To have USB2, you should have a separate USB 2.0 host controller with D+/D- connected to the same Type-C port. So the schematics is all on your side.

Comment: This is what I want exactly. However I feel suspicious that there are no products like this. Is there a specific reason behind it? There are tons of hubs with hdmi but nothing with displayport.

Comment: There are no specific reason for not having several DPs behind a hub. Here is one example, https://www.anandtech.com/show/12969/realtek-demonstrates-turnkey-usb-31-gen-2-hub